# Открывать только выбранный спойлер из множества

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть код для спойлера:

```js
$('.btnspoiler2').click(function() {
  if ($(this).text('open spoiler')) {
    $('.spoiler2').toggleClass('show')
  }
  if ($('.spoiler2').hasClass('show')) {
    $(this).text('close spoiler')
  }
})
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.btn {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #000;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.spoiler {
  height: 0;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
  -o-transition: .5s;
  transition: .5s;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.show {
  height: 130px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>SPOILER - 1</h2>
<button class="btn btnspoiler2">open spoiler</button>
<div class="spoiler spoiler2">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum iure, quaerat necessitatibus aspernatur tempora cumque pariatur similique ipsam ratione voluptatem. Officiis deserunt cupiditate nam veniam, nesciunt ipsa. Facilis reprehenderit quasi cum
    sint reiciendis ratione quo magnam, alias molestiae numquam nobis, officiis quia consequuntur, maiores ab deserunt excepturi libero nihil fuga.</p>
</div>
<hr>
<h2>SPOILER - 2</h2>
<button class="btn btnspoiler2">open spoiler</button>
<div class="spoiler spoiler2">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum iure, quaerat necessitatibus aspernatur tempora cumque pariatur similique ipsam ratione voluptatem. Officiis deserunt cupiditate nam veniam, nesciunt ipsa. Facilis reprehenderit quasi cum
    sint reiciendis ratione quo magnam, alias molestiae numquam nobis, officiis quia consequuntur, maiores ab deserunt excepturi libero nihil fuga.</p>
</div>
```

Всё работает, но если добавить больше одного спойлера на страницу, открываются все спойлеры, а хотелось чтобы открывался тот, по которому кликают.
Как это исправить?

Comment: "открываются все спойлеры" - неплохо бы написать, что должно происходить

Comment: Раскрывать спойлеры - плохая затея :) Котлы с анекдотами с конца ждут Вас! Работайте не со всей выборкой спойлеров, а с конкретным.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://api.jquery.com/next/

```js
$('.btnspoiler2').click(function() {
  var $spoiler = $(this).next('.spoiler2');
  if ($(this).text('open spoiler')) {
    $spoiler.toggleClass('show');
  }
  if ($spoiler.hasClass('show')) {
    $(this).text('close spoiler');
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.btn {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #000;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.spoiler {
  height: 0;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
  -o-transition: .5s;
  transition: .5s;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.show {
  height: 130px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>SPOILER - 1</h2>
<button class="btn btnspoiler2">open spoiler</button>
<div class="spoiler spoiler2">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum iure, quaerat necessitatibus aspernatur tempora cumque pariatur similique ipsam ratione voluptatem. Officiis deserunt cupiditate nam veniam, nesciunt ipsa. Facilis reprehenderit quasi cum
    sint reiciendis ratione quo magnam, alias molestiae numquam nobis, officiis quia consequuntur, maiores ab deserunt excepturi libero nihil fuga.</p>
</div>
<hr>
<h2>SPOILER - 2</h2>
<button class="btn btnspoiler2">open spoiler</button>
<div class="spoiler spoiler2">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum iure, quaerat necessitatibus aspernatur tempora cumque pariatur similique ipsam ratione voluptatem. Officiis deserunt cupiditate nam veniam, nesciunt ipsa. Facilis reprehenderit quasi cum
    sint reiciendis ratione quo magnam, alias molestiae numquam nobis, officiis quia consequuntur, maiores ab deserunt excepturi libero nihil fuga.</p>
</div>
```