# Как сделать, чтобы затемнение модального окна не касалось хэдера и футера?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, frontend

Существуют в проекте два модальных окна, которые вызываются при клике на кнопки входа или регистрации, которые находятся в хэдере. Задача состоит в том, что затемнение модального окна не должно действовать на хэдер и на футер. Впервые с этим сталкиваюсь
Код модального окна входа:

```js
<script>
    export default {
        name: 'app-login',
        props: {
          isOverlay: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: true
          }
        },
        data() {
            return {
            }
        },
      methods: {
        show () {
          this.$modal.show('app-login');
        }
      }
    }
</script>
```

```css
<style>

  .fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
   transition: opacity 0.2s;
  }

  .fade-enter, .fade-leave-to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .overlay {
    z-index: 99999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    pointer-events: none;
    background-color: #fff;
  }
  .container_login {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 35px;
    height: 350px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
   }
   .container_login.login_title {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: row;
   }
   .container_login.login_title.title {
      font-size: 20px;
      font-weight: 600;
      color: rgb(70, 66, 66);
   }
   .container_login.form_login {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
   }
   .container_login.form_login input {
      padding: 20px;
      margin: 17px 0;
      font-size: 15px;
      background-color: rgb(239, 239, 239);
    }
    .container_login.form_login.entry_btn {
      height: 50px;
      font-size: 15px;
      text-transform: capitalize;
      border-radius: 5px;
      box-shadow: none;
      color: #fff;
      background-color: rgb(153, 198, 31);
   }
   .container_login.href_pass {
     display: flex;
     margin: 20px 0;
   }
</style>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<template>
  <transition name="fade">
    <modal name="login"  width="430"  height="auto">
      <div class="container_login" :class="{login: true, overlay: isOverlay}">
        <div class="login_title">
          <p class="title">Добро пожаловать!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="form_login">
          <input type="email" placeholder="Ваш e-mail">
          <input type="password" placeholder="Пароль">
          <button class="entry_btn mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised">Войти</button>
        </div>
        <div class="href_pass">
          <a href="#">Забыли пароль?</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </modal>
  </transition>
</template>
```

Спасибо заранее за помощь!

Comment: Создайте минимально **воспроизводимый** пример. Сниппет в настройках окна ввода. И да - назначить им `z-index` больше чем у перекрытия пробовали?

Comment: z-index конечно пробовала задавать хэдеру и футеру больше чем у модального окна, а точнее z-index: 999999, не сработало(
А можно немного подробнее про сниппет?

Comment: В окне ввода/редактирования вверху есть иконки настроек - жырный, курсив и т. д. Среди них есть значок сниппета ( https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/ru/img/wmd-buttons.png?v=20e89c789eb5 - средний справа в конце). Туда вводите JS, HTML, CSS так, чтобы воспроизвелось Ваше поведение.

Comment: что-то не очень получилось, прощу прощения, мой первый опыт)

Comment: У всех первый раз волнующий, просто расслабьтесь :) Что именно не вышло?

Comment: сниппет вроде как добавила, а отображение рабочего кода не получилось

Comment: Поэтому и нужно довести код до более-менее рабочего состояния. [Вот пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/831793/207618).

Comment: прошу прощения, а как добавить vue в сниппет?
находит в скрипте ошибку

Comment: Вставить можно как обычный `script:src` с CDN.

Comment: дело в том что отдельно файла нет, этот скрипт находится внутри vue компонента модального окна входа, как и стили

Comment: Так в этом и суть - вытащить из `.vue` рабочий пример. Вытаскивайте и вставляйте.

Comment: Тогда позовите того, кто хоть немного понимает в этом деле.

Answer (score 1):

Опыт подсказывает, что проблема кроется либо в z-index, который у модального окна меньше чем у хедера, либо у вас где-то какой-то тег не закрытый. Тоже может быть. Покажите html пожалуйста.

Comment: Добавила код шаблона, теги закрыты

Comment: у хэдера и футера z-index: 999999

Comment: Ему наоборот надо